# Ao receber notificação do PagSeguro com o status do pagamento, dá erro 500 ao fazer push na minha API

Tags: java, api, restful

O código abaixo é o PUSH criado para que o PAGSeguro me envie a notificação do status do meu pagamento. Mas o erro retornado é 500, e no fórum deles nada de respostas até agora. Alguém que já passou por este problema pode me ajudar?

```
@PostMapping(value="/pagseguro-notificacao")
    public @ResponseBody
    String resgistrarNotificacao(
            @RequestParam(value = "notificationCode") String nCode,
            @RequestParam(value = "notificationType") String nType) {
        try {
            final PagSeguro pagSeguro = PagSeguro.instance(Credential.sellerCredential(sellerEmail,
                      sellerToken), PagSeguroEnv.PRODUCTION);

            TransactionDetail transaction = pagSeguro.transactions().search().byNotificationCode(nCode);

            if (transaction != null) {                
                atualizarStatusDoAnuncio(transaction);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Erro retornado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Salvo uma API pessimamente implementada, erro 500 é problema do lado deles. Googlando PagSeguro API e erro 500, a gente recebe uma chuva de links de ambiente sandbox instável, o que deve ser esse seu caso. A princípio, nada que você possa fazer, aparentemente.

Comment: Poderia colocar aqui o log do erro na sua máquina? Este erro é do lado da sua máquina.

Comment: @AristofanioGarcia debugando no servidor vi que o erro acontece nesse momento  TransactionDetail transaction = pagSeguro.transactions().search().byNotificationCode(nCode); Vou continuar debugando e informo o log, porque até agora não tinha conseguido debugar em produção.

Comment: Se o problema é aqui ```TransactionDetail transaction = pagSeguro.transactions().search().byNotificationCode(nCode);```. Provavelmente, seu problema é que não está na localização do nCode. Verifique se está ativado a notificação para dev, se os dados do token estão certos, etc... geralmente é coisa simples!!

Comment: @AristofanioGarcia deu certo, era uma notação que tinha que colocar nessa linha do credentials:  final PagSeguro pagSeguro = PagSeguro
         .instance(new CommonsLoggerFactory(), new JSEHttpClient(),
             Credential.sellerCredential(sellerEmail, sellerToken), PagSeguroEnv.PRODUCTION); estava sem esse new CommonsLoggerFactory e new JSEHttpClient  Obrigada pelas dicas de qualquer forma.